# Python + 2-D array slicing + valueerror: operands could not be broadcast together

Tags: python, arrays, slice

This has been kicking my butt for a bit....

I have the following information:

```
 1. a 1-D array of longitudes
 2. a 1-D array of latitudues
 3. a 2-D array of some quantity (sized len(lat),len(long))
```

What I want to do is get a subset of the array based on a range of latitudes and longitudes

I've tried something like this

```
ii = find( (lon >= xlims[0]) & (lon <= xlims[1]) )
jj = find( (lat >= ylims[0]) & (lat <= ylims[1]) )
z=array[jj, ii]

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

I have tried this using a boolean approach

ii = ( (lon >= xlims[0]) & (lon <= xlims[1]) )
jj = ( (lat >= ylims[0]) & (lat <= ylims[1]) )
```

but get the same error.

There is probably something subtle here I am missing... any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your `find` function does, but you can use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html).  First let's make some dummy data:

```
>>> lon = np.arange(10)
>>> lat = np.linspace(40,50,17)
>>> quant = np.random.random((len(lon),len(lat)))
>>> ii = (lon >= 2) & (lon < 5)
>>> jj = (lat >= 42) & (lat <= 44)
```

which gives me (for this data)

```
>>> ii
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> jj
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

When we feed this into `np.ix_`, we get something we can use to index:

```
>>> np.ix_(ii,jj)
(array([[2],
       [3],
       [4]]), array([[4, 5, 6]]))
```

and so

```
>>> quant[np.ix_(ii,jj)]
array([[ 0.51567424,  0.84138194,  0.6267137 ],
       [ 0.1865154 ,  0.7785198 ,  0.16720573],
       [ 0.80563691,  0.82990892,  0.28402503]])
```

Comment: Thanks... this is good stuff. The "find" is part of the numpy package and is similar to the Matlab find.... it returns the indices where the selected constraint is true. This is one of those times where the transition from Matlab to Python is not straight forward. So following your example to a larger array....     >>>>lon = np.arange(10)
>>> lat = np.linspace(40,50,17)
>>> quant = np.random.random((len(lon),len(lat)))

Comment: Do you mean `np.where`?